# How can I established connection to MySql Server?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to establish a connection with MySql server.

My PHP code is :

```
<?php
$dbhost = 'testhost.com';
$dbuser = 'testuser';
$dbpass = 'testpass';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die        
('Error connecting to mysql');
$dbname = 'testdb';
mysql_select_db($dbname);
?>
```

But it show the following error:

Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0 in F:\xampp\htdocs\db_connect123.php on line 6
Error connecting to mysql

In this situation i am totally confused because it work fine in localhost if i change the hostname.
Please, Give me a solution how can i resolve this problem and get connect with MySql server.

Comment: Are thos your real username/passwords? seems abit silly dont you think..

Comment: "reading initial communication packet" refer to an invalid hostname.. please check the Hostname correctly.

Comment: your server might not be allowing remote connections. Check to make sure remote connections are enabled on your server / hosting account. Are you on shared hosting?

Comment: Permissions. You need to set them on the remote mysql box so whatever account the web server is running as, has access.

Comment: If as @LawrenceCherone alludes to you have just told the entire world your user name and password, change them.

Comment: Already tried connecting seems im getting `reading initial communication packet` error ;p

Comment: You are trying to connect from am windows xampp installation to a live-database on carefreehomebuilders.com ?

Comment: @Lawrence Cherone, no this is not real username/password.

Comment: @Tony Hopkinson , please tell me how can i set them on the remote mysql box. Thanks everyday.Please help, i need to connect with my database.

Comment: Google php permission to remote mysql, might be some specific funnies for you setup, but the basic idea is Grant Some user on somehost some permission. It's not hard and you need to know this.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure my.ini is not:

```
bind-address = 127.0.0.1
port = 3306
```

Instead it should be:

```
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
port = 2083
```

Make sure that your user 'carefre2_polash' has a Host field of "%" (means any-host) under MySQL.

And if this is MySQL running on Windows, configure the native Windows firewall to accept incoming TCP on the above port number.

Comment: Please tell me the location of "my.ini". Thanks.

Comment: @Polash, I use WampDeveloper, but from my quick google search for Xampp, it looks like my.ini would be located in folder F:\xampp\mysql\bin\ for you. P.S., this assumes the server's my.ini, not the local my.ini (if you are connecting to mysql on a different system).

Comment: I changed the port but threre is no bind-address configuration in my.ini file. Please, help me.I am trying to connect to my hosting site form 2 days.but i can't.  Thanks

Comment: @Polash, your local my.ini is for the local instance of MySQL, it has no effect on your server's MySQL. You need to edit the server's my.ini.

Answer (score -1):

Use this Code Please, its a standart SQL connection code:

```
$link = mysql_connect('xhost', 'xuser_name', 'xpassword');
if (!$link) {
    die('Connect Error : ' . mysql_error()); 
}
mysql_set_charset('utf8', $link); // Encoding
$db_selected = mysql_selectdb('x_database', $link);
if (!$db_selected) {
    die ('DBselect Error : ' . mysql_error());
}
```

Good Luck and Have a nice day.

Comment: if there is now problem at all with your host,user,password and database selection there should not be a problem at all.

Comment: Well it's certainly nicer code, in that it would give a better message if a connection could be established to the server, but permssion to acces the database was denied. Doubt it will help the OP wth their current issue though.

Comment: Hello Blanktext, I tried by your code format but it's not working.Thanks.